# angularjs form submit data empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, algorithm, submit

Good day to all.

Have a form element

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="subMe()">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" />
</form>
```

and

```
$scope.subMe = function(){
  console.log( $scope.myForm ); // return empty object as {}
}
```

so, how I can see data in the form? There are many inputs elements will be in the future.

And is the best practice for check valid form in back-end?
Do as some like:

```
var _valid = $http.post();
if ( _valid) {
  if ( createUserSuccess() ){
    showSucceess();
  } else {
    showError();
  }
} else {
  showBadFilledFormElements();
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: how about `<form ng-model="myForm" ...`? That should add it to the scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no submit input or button, so `ng-submit` isn't what you would use to view the form data.

initialize an empty object in the scope of your form like so

```
myApp.controller('formController', function($scope) {
  $scope.formData = {};

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
      //do stuff on submit
  }
});
```

Then bind the `ng-model` in your markup like so

```
<div ng-controller="formController">
   <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
       <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="formData.name" value="" />
       <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
   </form>
    {{formData}}
</div>
```

You can view it with `{{formData}}` in the markup, within the scope of `formController`

EDIT: changed submit form function name to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Eric Olson's answer is pretty much correct. I just want to add something here. You might wanna checkout [ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm)

**ngForm**

Nestable alias of form directive. HTML does not allow nesting of form elements. It is useful to nest forms, for example if the validity of a sub-group of controls needs to be determined.

Note: the purpose of ngForm is to group controls, but not to be a replacement for the  tag with all of its capabilities (e.g. posting to the server, ...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add models to your form's input elements:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="subMe()">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="" ng-model="myForm.name" />
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" ng-model="myForm.email" />
</form>
```

and

```
$scope.subMe = function(){
  console.log( $scope.myForm ); // { name: "abc", email: "abc@test.com"}
}
```

I am not sure I understand the second part of your question, but you will want to create an [Angular Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for best practices when submitting your form data to your api.